# How to delete an inapp purchase item from my itunesconnect?

Tags: iphone

I have an application in which i am using an in app purchase item a subscriptions.due to some reason the application is rejected by apple.But my In app purchase item status is like developer action needed.and my delete option is not there.I want to delete that item from the list,I dont want to submit again with my new submission.Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the developer action needed action confused me too. But you have to select a purchase item in your app details in itunesconnect for your app anyway. So, just add a new purchase item, select this one in app details for your app, then submit your app.

All should be fine.

Comment: So i dont need to delete this in my new submission,because I am not using it in the new submission,when i submitt again i dont want this

Comment: Yes, thats right. Just make a second purchase item and you will see that you can choose which one you want to add for your app in your app details.